# Understanding initialization of weights and biases in Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, lstm

Presently I am using stacked LSTM and FC layer at last.

```
tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell
tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell
tf.nn.dynamic_rnn
tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected
```

According to my understanding, if I try to use any architecture defined under

```
tf.nn
```

class then weight initialization like

```
W2 = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(state_size, num_classes),dtype=tf.float32)
b2 = tf.Variable(np.zeros((1,num_classes)), dtype=tf.float32)
```

needs to be done and *tf.matmul* has to be used.

But for class under

```
tf.contrib
```

weight initialization happens automatically and *tf.matmul* may not be required.

Is my understanding correct? Please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the creation of weight and bias variables happens inside the cell, and then inside the fully connected layer. So, there is no need to define them explicitly. Also, when you are building the graph, Tensorflow doesn't initialize any of your variables. After, before you start executing nodes in the graph, you have you initialize the variables in the graph beforehand. Have a look:

```
# Some input
inputs = np.ones((5,4,3), dtype=np.float32)
# Cleaning the default graph before building it
tf.reset_default_graph()
# Creating a MultiRNNCell (The cell itself creates the weight and bias matrices)
cells = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(10) for _ in range(2)])
# A wrapper around the cells to ensure the recurrent relation
hidden_states, cell_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cells, inputs=inputs, dtype=tf.float32)
# Fully connected layer (What it does is create a W and b matrices and performs tf.matmul and then tf.add)
logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(hidden_states[-1], num_outputs=2, activation_fn=None)
# A new session
sess = tf.Session()
# All variables that were created above (implicitly, by creating a cell and a fully connected layer) will be initialized
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
# Executing the last node in the graph
sess.run(logits)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer.
If i can have you for another 2mins , Instead of using FC layer I can go by using 
    tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits to reduce the depth and normalize, right ?

Comment: `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` is a loss function, and it has nothing to do with the fully connected layer. What do you want to do? Please post another question with a more elaborate explanation of your goal and I will give my best to answer it.

Comment: Ok. I would do that.